# Android - setQueryHint("search here"); doesn't work in SearchView

Tags: android

I made this search view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
      android:id="@+id/searchView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      />
```

and in MainActivity I got the search view and put a hint

```
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    searchView.setQueryHint("search here");
```

but it doesn't work and the hint didn't appear, any help?

Comment: And the search view is empty?

Comment: the search view has its search icon only , and when i write anything it appears .
the problem is with the hint